# Fail to run `sudo ./sbin/start-dfs.sh` with Hadoop3.0.0 beta1 in Ubuntu 16.04(VMware Workstation14)

Tags: java, ubuntu, hadoop, ssh

I try to deploy a distributed system with Hadoop3.0.0beta1 in Ubuntu16.04, and I have configured the ssh protocol and all my nodes can login without password.

But When I try to run `sudo ./sbin/start-dfs.sh` It prompt like this:

```
Starting namenodes on [Hadoop-NameNode]
Hadoop-NameNode: Permission denied (publickey,password).
pdsh@Hadoop-NameNode: Hadoop-NameNode: ssh exited with exit code 255
Starting datanodes
Hadoop-DataNode-1: Permission denied (publickey,password).
pdsh@Hadoop-NameNode: Hadoop-DataNode-1: ssh exited with exit code 255
Starting secondary namenodes [Hadoop-NameNode]
Hadoop-NameNode: Permission denied (publickey,password).
pdsh@Hadoop-NameNode: Hadoop-NameNode: ssh exited with exit code 255
```

I don't know why, all nodes can ping and login without password, I have seen that someone said that 'do not use `sudo`', I have tried but it not work.

I guess may be I used virtual machine to install my Ubuntu system, and it caused some problems in ssh?

I'm looking forward to your help, Thanks again.

Comment: Do you use 'root'  user

Comment: No I don't. but I have already used 'sudo' when I running this command. @H.king

Comment: I try to use 'root' user and redo all things from beginning and it solved my problem. Although I still do not know why it happened, but thank you so much@H.king!

Comment: It caused by your Secret key file problem   .